# When referencing an array of dates and times in a formula when using Excel I sometimes get unexpected outputs

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-365

I ran into some unexpected behavior when handling cells with dates and times in the form of "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm" and as you can see in the second image the formula "=A2:A5" only gives the correct dates and times for the first row, I don't know where the other numbers come from. Similar when using LEFT() but I only get unexpected outcomes. There's no issue when only referencing one cell at a time. If anyone could explain why this happens and suggest a fix that'd be great

Dates in column A

[image]

Formula gives unexpected behavior

[image]

Another example of unexpected behavior

[image]

Version:
Microsoft® Excel® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2203 Build 16.0.15028.20152) 64-bit

Comment: The cells need to formatted as date/time.  Excel stores dates as a double and the format shows it correctly.  Those cells are set to General and not Date.

Comment: in that value an addition of 1 to the value is "the next day", the decimal portion counts `1/(24*60*60)` for each second; i.e. noon on a day is 0.5 added to the day offset from 1899-12-30 (day 0 in LibreOffice)

Answer (score 0):

You can format the cell to **YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm**:
[image]